# How to get receipts from near-api-js?

Tags: nearprotocol

When calling a change function a function with near-api-js, how can I get the receipt of the transaction?

I've tried:

```js
const response = await contract.changeMethod({args})
console.log(response)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71004135/1471485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `functionCall` method on the wallet to get the receipt of the transaction.

```ts
const response = await wallet.account().functionCall({
 contractId: 'yourContractId',
 methodName: 'changeMethod',
 args,
})
```

More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71004135/1471485).

Comment: Thanks John, I got the receipt by adding ```const { transaction_outcome: txo, status } = result; console.log(`receipt: ${txo.outcome.receipt_ids}`);``` to the above code